# How do I extract the country code from this HTML on OpenRefine?

Tags: html, iso, openrefine, country-codes

I'm a newbie in all this, and don't even know how to refer to some terms correctly, sorry if I'm not very good at explaining myself. I'm trying to find a way to extract the country code, in my case "códigoIso", from the HTML I managed to obtain on OpenRefine. We've been asked to EXTRACT, but not told how to do it, not even a hint on what languge to use, or how GREL works. In fact, we haven't been explained how to do any of it.
I've searched everywhere but can't find the correct "expression", so I can parse this, and get the only information I need: the ISO value of the country code, 32.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:dbpprop="http://dbpedia.org/property/"
    xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
    version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0"
    xml:lang="es"
>


<!-- header -->
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>About: Argentina</title>
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rdf+xml"        href="http://es.dbpedia.org/data/Argentina.rdf" title="Structured Descriptor Document (RDF/XML format)" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/n3"            href="http://es.dbpedia.org/data/Argentina.n3" title="Structured Descriptor Document (N3 format)" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/turtle"            href="http://es.dbpedia.org/data/Argentina.ttl" title="Structured Descriptor Document (Turtle format)" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/json+rdf"       href="http://es.dbpedia.org/data/Argentina.jrdf" title="Structured Descriptor Document (RDF/JSON format)" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/json"       href="http://es.dbpedia.org/data/Argentina.json" title="Structured Descriptor Document (RDF/JSON format)" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml"       href="http://es.dbpedia.org/data/Argentina.atom" title="OData (Atom+Feed format)" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/plain"             href="http://es.dbpedia.org/data/Argentina.ntriples" title="Structured Descriptor Document (N-Triples format)" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/csv"               href="http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org&amp;query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina%3E&amp;format=text%2Fcsv" title="Structured Descriptor Document (CSV format)" />
    
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/microdata+json" href="http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org&amp;query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina%3E&amp;format=application%2Fmicrodata%2Bjson" title="Structured Descriptor Document (Microdata/JSON format)" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html"          href="http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org&amp;query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina%3E&amp;format=text%2Fhtml" title="Structured Descriptor Document (Microdata/HTML format)" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/ld+json"        href="http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org&amp;query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina%3E&amp;format=application%2Fjson-ld" title="Structured Descriptor Document (JSON-LD format)" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/x-html-script-ld+json" href="http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org&amp;query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina%3E&amp;format=text%2Fx-html-script-ld%2Bjson" title="Structured Descriptor Document (HTML with embedded JSON-LD)" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/x-html-script-turtle"  href="http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org&amp;query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina%3E&amp;format=text%2Fx-html-script-turtle" title="Structured Descriptor Document (HTML with embedded Turtle)" />
    <link rel="timegate" type="text/html"           href="http://dbpedia.mementodepot.org/timegate/http://es.dbpedia.org/page/Argentina" title="Time Machine" />
    <link rel="foaf:primarytopic"               href="http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Argentina"/>
    <link rev="describedby"                     href="http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Argentina"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"          href="/statics/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"          href="/statics/css/dbpedia.css" />
</head>
<body about="http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Argentina">
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dbp-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://es.dbpedia.org" title="About DBpedia" style="color: #2c5078">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.imgur.com/IeeSN7U.png" alt="About DBpedia" style="display: inline-block;  margin-top: -15px;width:70px;height:49px;"/>
        </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.upm.es/" title="About UPM" style="color: #2c5078">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.upm.es/sfs/Rectorado/Gabinete%20del%20Rector/Logos/UPM/Logotipo%20con%20Leyenda/LOGOTIPO%20leyenda%20color%20PNG.png" alt="About UPM" style="display: inline-block; margin-top: -20px;width:120px;height:56px;">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="dbp-navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="active" href="/fct/" title="Switch to /fct endpoint"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" aria-hidden="true"></span> Faceted Browser </a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="/sparql/" title="Switch to /sparql endpoint"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" aria-hidden="true"></span> Sparql Endpoint </a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span> Browse using <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/describe/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina">OpenLink Faceted Browser</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/rdf-editor/#/editor?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina&amp;view=statements">OpenLink Structured Data Editor</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://en.lodlive.it/?http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina">LodLive Browser</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://lodmilla.sztaki.hu/lodmilla/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina">LODmilla Browser</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span> Formats <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>&nbsp;RDF:</li>
            <li><a href="http://es.dbpedia.org/data/Argentina.ntriples">N-Triples</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://es.dbpedia.org/data/Argentina.n3">N3</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://es.dbpedia.org/data/Argentina.ttl">Turtle</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://es.dbpedia.org/data/Argentina.json">JSON</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://es.dbpedia.org/data/Argentina.rdf">XML</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>&nbsp;OData:</li>
            <li><a href="http://es.dbpedia.org/data/Argentina.atom">Atom</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://es.dbpedia.org/data/Argentina.jsod">JSON</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>&nbsp;Microdata:</li>
            <li><a href="http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org&amp;query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina%3E&amp;format=application%2Fmicrodata%2Bjson">JSON</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org&amp;query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina%3E&amp;format=text%2Fhtml">HTML</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>&nbsp;Embedded:</li>
            <li><a href="http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org&amp;query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina%3E&amp;format=text%2Fx-html-script-ld%2Bjson">JSON</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org&amp;query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina%3E&amp;format=text%2Fx-html-script-turtle">Turtle</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
            
            <li><a href="http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org&amp;query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina%3E&amp;format=text%2Fcsv">CSV</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org&amp;query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fes.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArgentina%3E&amp;format=application%2Fjson-ld">JSON-LD</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<!-- page-header -->
    <div class="page-header">
    <!-- div class="pull-right">
        <a href="http://es.dbpedia.org" title="About DBpedia">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/statics/images/dbpedia_logo_land_120.png" alt="About DBpedia"/>
        </a>
    </div -->
    <h1 id="title">About:
        <a href="http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Argentina">Argentina</a>
    </h1>
    <div class="page-resource-uri">
        An Entity of Type : <a href="http://es.dbpedia.org/ontology/Location">Location</a>,
        from Named Graph : <a href="http://es.dbpedia.org">http://es.dbpedia.org</a>,
        within Data Space : <a href="http://es.dbpedia.org">es.dbpedia.org</a>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- page-header -->
<!-- row -->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p class="lead">Argentina, oficialmente República Argentina,​ es un país soberano de América del Sur, ubicado en el extremo sur y sudeste de dicho subcontinente. Adopta la forma de gobierno republicana, democrática, representativa y federal. Integra el Mercosur —bloque del que fue fundador en 1991—, la Unión de Naciones Sudamericanas (Unasur), la Comunidad de Estados Latinoamericanos y Caribeños (CELAC) y la Organización de Estados Americanos (OEA).</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <!-- proptable -->
        <table class="description table table-striped">
        <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-3">Property</th>
        <th class="col-xs-9">Value</th>
        </tr>
<tr class="odd"><td class="property"><a class="uri" href="http://es.dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract" title="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract"><small>dbo:</small>abstract</a>
</td><td><ul>
```

There's a long section after, with more information about the Country, but this is the part where the ISO code is.

```
            <li>
                <span class="literal">
                    <span property="prop-es:códigoIso" xmlns:prop-es="http://es.dbpedia.org/property/">32</span>
                    <small> (xsd:integer)</small>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td class="property">
        <a class="uri" href="http://es.dbpedia.org/property/códigoTelefónico">
            <small>prop-es:</small>códigoTelefónico
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ul>
```

I have tried everything I could find on the topic, but keep getting errors, and I'm becoming desperate.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Ps: Thank you for the corrections I got so far!

Comment: This is not JSON. Its HTML.

Comment: thank u! I've edited my message, I hope someone can help.

Comment: Hi. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve